# Button moves up when Listview items is small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have situation that i need to use button after Listview.Its working correctly when Listview's item is more but doesn't worked for me when it is less.So can any one advice me how to make my button stable at the bottom of my layout.

Here i'm attaching xml snippet and images.Please have a look and respond to me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/invScanType"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_full"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_fullTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/itemno"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pick_seq"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mseordqty"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mseshpqty"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/uom"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mseshipvia"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/msecomments"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_msefull"
                style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_mse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_mseExit"               
            style="@style/ButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/action_exit_in" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Images

[image]

[image]

I always want to have First Image even if Listview's item is less.

Comment: Change your main layout *height* to *match_parent* `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

Comment: Appreciate your help...Thanks. @Rami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

- Change the Parent layout to a RelativeLayout.
- Add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the second LinearLayout `lay_mse`.

Answer (score 0):

If the top view has a height of match parent then I I think that alignparentbottom = true might work.

Answer (score 0):

use this to align the view at the bottom

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Note: your parent layout must be RelativeLayout.